# Difference between HTTPServlet and APIMethod - AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

So I am trying to teach myself backend development and have gone with Google App Engine to help me.

**My Question is:**
What is the difference between an HTTP Servlet and an API Method?

They seem to do the same thing for me.
Lets use the example of an app where you take brief notes on a client and send them to the server to process:

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = "POST")
public final String sendShortNote(@Named("note") final String note) throws ServiceException {
    // Do POSTlike things here
}
```

and setting up an HTTPServlet that handles doPost and retrieves the note from the body:

```
public class NoteServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getParameter("note");
    //continue to do things and return a response.
}
```

From what I see, the Servlet allows me to add things to the HTTP body while the ApiMethod just adds the parameters as a query url, which makes the Servlet more secure?

Also, the Servlet allows me to return multiple values through a response while the APIMethod only allows me to return a single value.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, yes you can technically do similar things with both API methods and with HTTPservlet.

When you build an HTTPservlet, it's a handler you mapped in your [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_About_appengine_web_xml), that you then need to code.

When you build an APImethod, it's actually an "[Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)", which exposes methods that can run on backend instances.

Normally endpoints are a bit more used to create web backends, so mostly used with mobile devices.